# IIS Experss, доступ к большому видео-файлу

Tags: asp.net-mvc, видео, iis-express

Имею iis express, который шел в паке от VS17 enterprise.

Мною на iis express в данный момент осуществляется развертывание веб-приложения asp.net. В данном приложении осуществляю загрузку видео. Видео загружается в папку на сервере.
Размер видео в среднем 4 гб и продолжительностью, также в среднем, 1.5 ч.;

Использую git.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
В релизной версии проекта работает загрузка нормально.

В ветке разработки, которая продолжается от последнего релиза, проведены некоторые изменения, не затрагивающие работу с видео или конфигом iis.

Проблема такая: При попытке воспроизведения 'большого' видео iis отказывается его воспроизводить.
По директ линку (e.g. http://localhost:2020/Videos/filename.mp4) в консоль разработчика пишется следующая строчка:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: "http://localhost:2020/Videos/filename.mp4"

Дефолтный html плеер выводит [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2b9v.jpg) (т.е. ничего)

*Пробовал тыкать в конфиге maxRequestLenght до Int.MaxValue - результату нуль.*

Comment: Ну ошибка показывает, что сохраненный вариант видео почему то считается документом. Возможно стоит проверить 1) То с какими параметрами сохраняется файл (mime-type) 2) С какими мимтайпами работает ваше приложение - возможно вы просто оставили дефолтные настройки. К сожалению сам с такой проблемой не сталкивался. Попробуйте передавать файлы поменьше и других типов и проверьте что iis их принудительно не приводит к одному типу. Т.е. если ошибка повторится для mp3 файлов и для PNG - надо искать то, что их приводит к единому типу.

Comment: Так все же IIS отказывается воспроизводить - или браузер?

Comment: @alexoander, 1. Файл сохраняется с тем же расширением, что и передается. Т.е. напрямую сохраненный файл воспроизводится без проблем. 2. Настройки iis у меня дефолтные. (по дефолту mime-type там mp4 прописан уже)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, IIS. Браузер воспроизводит по ссылке на файл (C:/path/to/file.mp4)

Comment: Забыл упомянуть - на маленьких видео (тестил на 30 мин, 600 мб) - IIS нормально воспроизводит.

Comment: У вас конфликт MIME-типа документа. Тест на MIME придумали что б защитится от вирусов, и так же случаев, когда допустим вместо видео находится ворд документ, который может вызвать проблемы с кодеками. Скорее всего большой mp4 имеет другой MIME тип. Прийдётся вам определить MIME и выровнять несоответствие.

Comment: @nick_n_a вы бы хоть проверили. video/mp4 - это корректный тип для mp4-файла с видео.

Comment: У вас это во всех браузерах или только в хроме, как в [этом вопросе](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-zip)?

Comment: @AK, во всех браузерах видео не воспроизводится. В Хроме в консоль пишется указанная строка. (хром\опера\edge тестил)